# List of junctions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I would like to get a list of junctions' coordinates in a radius around a given coordinate. I figured there should be a way to extract the coordinates of wherever two roads meet, however I can't find it. Please advise!

Comment: How did you  figure that there should be a way to extract the coordinates of wherever two roads meet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is not available in the Google Maps API v3.